# regex to find missing closing tag in xml

Tags: python, regex, xml

I have some xml that's coming out a nlp extraction tool with some mismatched tags. I'm attempting to then use regex to find the mismatched tags and correct the issue, but I'm getting stuck on the regex part.

I am able to select all instances of the `<Name>` tag, but I only want to select those *without* a closing tag and use replace to add a matching closing tag. How do I narrow it down, and replace correctly?

Actual results of `xx` is `(<Name>.*)</Name>` but I need it to be `<Name>Margrethe II</Name>`.

**Find:** `<Name>.*`

**Replace:** `(<Name>.*)</Name>`

```
import re

mmt = """<Sovereigns>
    <Queens>
        <Queen>
            <Name>Elizabeth II</Name>
            <Country>Great Britain and Northern Ireland</Country>
        </Queen>
        <Queen>
            <Name>Margrethe II
            <Country>Denmark</Name></Country>
        </Queen>
    </Queens>
</Sovereigns>"""

# remove extra closing tag
x = re.sub("</Name><", "<", mmt)
# add closing tag to those missing
xx = re.sub("<Name>.*", "(<Name>.*)</Name>", mmt)
```

Comment: Do these find/replace operations only ever need to take place on single lines?

Comment: I think this might be illegal, but am not sure `<Name>Margrethe II
            <Country>Denmark</Name></Country>`

Comment: Find `r"(?s)(<Name>(?:(?!<).)*(?=<|$)(?!</Name>))"` replace `r"\1</Name>"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want your `xx` line to be:

```
xx = re.sub("<Name>(?!.*</Name>)(.*)", r"<Name>\1</Name>", mmt)
```

1. `<Name>` Matches `<Name>`
2. `(?!.*</Name>)` A *negative lookahead* that says that the rest of the line must not contain `</Name>`
3. `(.*)` Matches the rest of the line in capture group 1.

The replacement contains a back reference to capture group 1.

Comment: But this all presupposes that the these the opening and closing `<Name>` and `</Name>` tags are all on a single line. You also have the additional problem of: `<Country>Denmark</Name></Country>`.

Comment: I messed it up in my original post but `<Country>Denmark</Name></Country>` is taken care of by `x = re.sub("</Name><", "<", mmt)`. And in my actual data I have yet to run across any tags that weren't on a single line (thankfully). But this looks like exactly what I needed, thank you!

Comment: I am always willing to learn, so whoever downvoted this, please do me the favor of telling me where this falls short.